# Dynamic table - auto-show

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code where I edit the field of a row in a table, but I want it to be more Dynamic, that is, when editing a field it jumps to the next field where I will edit. I have a success function where I should jump to the next field to edit what the Item would be, but I do not know why it does not work.

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
     //WITH THIS CODE I COULD JUMP BUT THE LIST GIVE A ERROR AND CREATE A NEW TR WITH TD
           $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: ITEM,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have seen an example on the next page. [link](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) you must press the checkbox auto-open next field at the moment of editing this jump to the next field to edit. I would like something like that, I hope I have explained myself well.

UPDATE: I add a line of code in my success function but the select give a error `Error when loading list` and in the table create a new `<tr> with <td>`

Comment: When I run the code it is working fine nah? what is the issue?

Comment: @acmsohail If I change the task I want  jump to the select Item

Comment: change the task you mean click `tab` should take to the `item` field?

Comment: in the `success: function(response)` automatically jump to the select field

Comment: Please check my answer. I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just changed `$(this).parent().find(".Item").editable('toggle');` to `$(this).parent().find(".Item").click();`

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
     //WITH THIS CODE I COULD JUMP BUT THE LIST GIVE A ERROR AND CREATE A NEW TR WITH TD
           $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: ITEM,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think that your error show up because there is no default value at first try changing item then change text in your snippet

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
          
           //CODE TO JUMP TO THE SELECT 
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: ITEM,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });

    $('#table .task').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
     
      if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
          var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.task');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            $next.editable('show');
        }, 300);
      }
   });
   
   $('#table .Item').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
     
      if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
          var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.Item');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            $next.editable('show');
        }, 300);
      }
   });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: doesn't jump to the select field, jump to the `tr` of the ID

Comment: What do you mean by selected field?

Comment: $(this).parent().find('.Item').editable('show');  try this and check

Answer (score 1):

Please try again this. This will help you :)

```js
$('#table').editable({
  container: 'body',
  selector: 'td.task',
  title: 'task',
  type: "POST",
  showbuttons: false,
  type: 'text',
  validate: function(value) {
    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
      return 'Empty!';
    }
  },
  success: function(response) {

    //CODE TO JUMP TO THE SELECT 
  }
});
var ITEM = [];
$.each({
  "Item1": "Item1",
  "Item2": "Item2",
  "Item3": "Item3",
  "Item4": "Item4"
}, function(k, v) {
  ITEM.push({
    value: k,
    text: v
  });
});

$('#table').editable({
  container: 'body',
  selector: 'td.Item',
  title: 'Item',
  type: "POST",
  showbuttons: false,
  source: ITEM,
  validate: function(value) {
    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
      return 'Empty!';
    }
  }
});

$('#table .task').on('hidden', function(e, reason) {

  if (reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
    $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
      <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
      <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, since you linked to the working example, I was able to examine the code. You can do this, by the way, by simply opening up the developer tools in your browser. I use Chrome, so for me that's just F12. In the source code, I found the following:

```
   $('#user .editable').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
        if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
            var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.editable');
            if($('#autoopen').is(':checked')) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $next.editable('show');
                }, 300); 
            } else {
                $next.focus();
            } 
        }
   });
```

The code reads almost like English, so it is fairly easy to follow I think.
When the editor is closed, we first check for the reason why it closed.
The code then finds the next field and pops open the editor if the "auto-open next textfield" is checked. It's interesting to see here that this is done with a timeout instead of just calling `$next.editable('show');` That might be important or just for show.

In your code, you'll want to be able to find some unifying selector for your items. Easiest way to do it, I think, is to just add an `.editable` to your original source and call it like they do in the demo.

So, for your HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="editable task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="editable Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="editable task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="editable Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice the added class on the `td` tags. (EDIT: derp, didn't notice there was already a class attribute)

Then, you can emulate the demo js code, but be careful here because the `$next` variable cannot be selected in the same way. Your DOM layout is not the same since you have more than one editable cell in a row:

```
   $('#table .editable').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
        if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
            var $next = $(this).nextAll().find('.editable');
            if ($next.length > 0) {
                $next = $next[0];
            } else {
                $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.editable');
                if ($next.length > 0) {
                    $next = $next[0];
                } else {
                    return; // No editable fields remaining.
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function() { $next.editable('show'); }, 300); 
        }
   });
```

I should disclaim that I have not tested the above, but it should give you a good starting point to get going. The selection of the next field can probably be done a lot better than what I have, but I just don't have the testing environment to check this out properly.

**EDIT**: I've noticed that perhapse you only want to move on to the select field, but not necessarily from the select to the item in the next row. In that case, the code is a little bit simpler.

First off, there is no need for the `editable` class, so you can just use the html code you already have, but in the js, you need to address the selectors correctly:

```
   $('#table .task').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
        if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
            var $next = $(this).nextAll().find('.Item');
            setTimeout(function() { $next.editable('show'); }, 300); 
        }
   });
```

And that should be it. When the editor on the select closes, the next field will not be selected automatically.

Comment: Ooof, I somehow missed the fact you don't have the checkbox that the demo had. This is what happens when you don't have a test environment. Anyway, I think that should all work.

Comment: I add this line of code in my success function `$(this).parent().find(".Item").editable('toggle');` but the list give an error in the display list

Comment: check my snippet `Error when loading list`